# Retorno de teste em uma API

Tags: php, json, api, postman

Estou testando um modo de pegar dados de um banco com uma API simples, não sei se esta certa, se poderem me dar uma ajuda

Queria que ela funcionasse via POST, mas os testes no **POSTMAN** so retorna se eu colocar **REQUEST**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$chave_de_acesso = "teste";

 if($_POST['chave_de_acesso'] == $chave_de_acesso){    

        $array = array(
                "acesso" => 'ok'
        );   

   } else {

            $array = array(
              "acesso" => 'erro'
            );   

   }

echo  json_encode($array);
```

Comment: No caso, o só retorna pelo `REQUEST` se você estiver usando `$_GET` né? Ou pelo `$_POST` também não dá nada?

Comment: @CypherPotato, Pelo POST não da nada, somente quando coloco REQUEST, mas continuo com o Metodo POST